# Generate non-versioned jar-entries in manifest's classpath with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, classpath, manifest

To achieve an executable jar-file, I add the following to the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The result is (MANIFEST.MF)

```
...
Class-Path: library1-8.10-SNAPSHOT.jar hessian-4.0.7.jar library2-8.10-SNAPSHOT.jar json-lib-2.2.3-jdk15.jar ezmorph-1.0.6.jar library3-8.10-SNAPSHOT.jar commons-io-1.4.jar
...
```

and so forth

That means, the jar's version is included with the file-name. I'd like it to have without it:

```
Class-Path: library.jar hessian.jar library2.jar json-lib.jar ezmorph.jar library3.jar commons-io.jar
```

simply because that's the way they're named in the lib-folder.

We are using Maven 2.2, so classpathLayoutType and customClasspathLayout aren't available (if they'd help at all).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you clarify the specific question you're asking?

Comment: With Maven, How can I generate a classpath that contains non-versioned library names. I.e abc.jar instead of abc-1.3.4.jar.

Answer (score 12):

Why are they without a version in the `lib` directory? Aren't you using [proper dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), something that Maven provides (and is one of the main reasons to use Maven in the first place)?

It is a bad idea to have jars without a version, since you can't easily tell which version of a library is installed on a system. The problem isn't that the `Class-Path` is wrong, but that the libraries should be versioned. There's a problem in the rest of the build. So, how do you declare dependencies, and how do you build the final package?

If you really want to do that, then you can [customize the maven-archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Altering_The_Classpath:_Using_a_Custom_Classpath_Format), specifying that the `classpathLayoutType` should be `custom`, and the `customClasspathLayout` should be `${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}`. For example:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                    <customClasspathLayout>lib/${artifact.artifactId}${artifact.dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                    <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

(note that I added a `lib/` prefix, feel free to remove it or replace it with whatever you need)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact, that we use unversioned libraries in the built application, doesn't imply an inmproper dependency management, does it? ;-) There are reasons for that, but, ok, I'll consider your advice. Apart from that, coming back to my question: is it possible to generate a classpath without version numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately we are using Maven 2.2 (see my initial post), and there, this two tags (classpathLayout and customClasspathLayout) aren't available. But, thanks a lot anyway. I have this three choices now: 1) using versioned jars, 2) upgrade to Maven 2.4 (at least), 3) use another way instead of Maven.

Comment: But this is the configuration for the Maven Archiver plugin, which should work with Maven 2.2 as well. Check which version of `maven-jar-plugin` you're using with `mvn help:effective-pom`; support for these configurations was introduced in `maven-archiver 2.4`, which is used starting with `maven-jar-plugin 2.3`, which should work with [`maven 2.0.6+`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3/maven-jar-plugin-2.3.pom).

Comment: There is no `Maven 2.4`, the latest release on the `2.x` branch is 2.2.1. The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Altering_The_Classpath%3a_Using_a_Custom_Classpath_Format) refers to the version of the `maven-archiver` component, which isn't the same as the `maven-core` version. Maven is highly modular, so each part can have its own version number. This is good since everything can be upgraded as needed without waiting for a big release of everything, although it is confusing...

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu Is it possible to strip the versions for some groupId's only in the manifest?

Comment: @Neel Not directly, but you could generate your own manifest from scratch. You can [generate one using Velocity](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/process-mojo.html), then [use the outcome](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html).

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu Thanks for introducing me to the velocity plugin. I can definitely try the second part of your solution. But I am not sure how to generate the MANIFEST. I am currently using the jar plugin. Can you please share some code?